# Kotlin - What does this <MyInterface>.() do?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I see code in Android JetPack Compose -

```
content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
```

What does `<interface>.()` do? What is it called? Is there any documentation?

I tried writing a small snippet -

```
interface testI {

}

typealias test = testI.() -> Unit
```

But I cannot use `test` or `testI` at all... Can someone help me understand what this snippet is doing and what is it called?

Comment: It is called [function literal with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver)

Comment: In kotlin, you can say it is An Extension Function. You can use it to make a function without a class instance and you can use it without modifying the original class

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html

Comment: @ChiragThummar, that’s not an extension function. There are some related concepts concerning the syntax, but it is what Ricky Mo said.

Answer (score 1):

```
content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
```

This means content inside your Composable can access to BoxScope `Modifier`s.

```
@LayoutScopeMarker
@Immutable
interface BoxScope {
    /**
     * Pull the content element to a specific [Alignment] within the [Box]. This alignment will
     * have priority over the [Box]'s `alignment` parameter.
     */
    @Stable
    fun Modifier.align(alignment: Alignment): Modifier

    /**
     * Size the element to match the size of the [Box] after all other content elements have
     * been measured.
     *
     * The element using this modifier does not take part in defining the size of the [Box].
     * Instead, it matches the size of the [Box] after all other children (not using
     * matchParentSize() modifier) have been measured to obtain the [Box]'s size.
     * In contrast, a general-purpose [Modifier.fillMaxSize] modifier, which makes an element
     * occupy all available space, will take part in defining the size of the [Box]. Consequently,
     * using it for an element inside a [Box] will make the [Box] itself always fill the
     * available space.
     */
    @Stable
    fun Modifier.matchParentSize(): Modifier
}
```

This allows you to access these scoped modifiers in your Composable without wrapping your Composables inside a Box every time you use a custom Composable if you wish to apply align for instance. `Modifier.align` is available only in BoxScope.

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    // This is not allowed
//    content()

    Box(modifier) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Since receiver of content is BoxScope you can call content lambda only inside BoxScope.

Now when you use it

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {

    MyComposable(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {// This is boxScope, without using a Box you can access its modifiers
        Text(text = "Text", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
    }
}
```

you can access Modifier.align(Alignment.Center) because Text composable is placed inside `BoxScope`.

There are also RowScope, ColumnScope and Lazy scopes by default. You can also define your own scopes and your own scoped modifiers that would only available for specific Composables.